# Change text fields that were populated by php?

Tags: php

So I have a few text fields that were populated from a php table like so:

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="plu" value="<?php echo $plu; ?>" />
```

Now I would like it so when this form is submitted, I can resubmit these fields into a table if the text in the fields is changed or even if it isn't. Only problem is on my new php page when I get the variables using post, they come us as empty. Am I doing this the wrong way?

EDIT: got it. stupid brain.

Comment: show your code that gets the POST values

Comment: Also, if `$title`, `$price` or `$plu` contain a `"` character, displaying the HTML will break.

Comment: Oh man, I was using id="title" instead of name="title. I hate Mondays.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your form is like below:

```
<form action="/your-php-page.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="plu" value="<?php echo $plu; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

In "your-php-page.php", you should receive the variables like so.

```
<?php
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $plu = $_POST['plu'];

    //echo them so we can see whats going on.
    echo 'Title: '.$title.'<br/>Price: '.$price.'<br/>PLU: '.$plu;

    // For Debugging try var_dumping $_POST
    var_dump($_POST); // This will show all the posted variables only
    var_dump($_REQUEST) // This will show all GET & Posted variables.

?>
```

**If you are getting blank variables when the input has a value inside it.**
1. Check you are posting to the right page (check your paths, absolute/relative).
2. Check you **php.ini** for these values, and make sure they are correct:

- variables_order contains the letter P
- post_max_size is set to a reasonable value (e.g. 8 MB)